# How to create a generic return type for an abstract class override method

Tags: java, android, generics, types

I have an abstract class that gets implemented by Java and by Android.  This class has a method that needs to return a generic Cursor so that the implementations can return their respective cursors.

My abstract class:

```
public abstract class DatabaseAdapter {

protected abstract com.domain.database.Cursor<?> executeQuery(String command);      

}
```

The cursor type:

```
public final class Cursor<T> {

private T value = null;

public void setValue(T value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public T getValue() {
    return value;
}
    }
```

As stated earlier, I want the implementing method to return either a Java cursor or and Android cursor depending upon the situation.  I can create the abstract classes just fine but when I try to implement, I get a compile error.  I am apparently not understanding polymorphism very well here.

The implementing method

```
public Cursor executeQuery(String query){
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);
return cursor;      
}
```

where Cursor is **android.database.Cursor**

Comment: And what compiler error did you get?? Can you post it here??

Comment: The return type is incompatible with DatabaseAdapter.executeQuery(String)

Comment: What is the fully qualified name of the return type `Cursor` in `executeQuery` implementation.. Prabably that is the problemm..

Comment: Your implementation should return this (`com.domain.database.Cursor<?>`) type of Cursor..   Your compiler error clearly says that : - `android.database.Cursor` is not compatible with `com.domain.database.Cursor<?>`.. Also, it should be Generic Cursor..

Comment: So, how to I set up the abstract class so that I can return either android.database.cursor OR java.awt.Cursor?  As The topic states.

Comment: It would be typical.. For that you would have to make an `Adaptor`.. Which will convert between different types of Cursor.. From `com.domain.database.Cursor` to `android.database.Cursor` and to `java.awt.Cursor`

Comment: That's a little cryptic.  Could you please explain around the context provided here?  Thanks :^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can remove `com.domain.database.Cursor`, but I may be wrong.

My solution is to make `DatabaseAdapter` generic, not `Cursor`.

```
/**
 * @param C the type of the Cursor this adapter returns
 */
public abstract class DatabaseAdapter<C> {
    protected abstract C executeQuery(String command);      
}
```

Then you implement like this:

```
public class AndroidDatabaseAdapter extends DatabaseAdapter<android.database.Cursor> {
    public Cursor executeQuery(String query){
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my missing link - Thank you very much!